# Button with icon missing in iOS simulator?

Tags: css

Video icon is ok on **Firefox browser** as below:

[align top http://www.kerrydeaf.com/net.png](http://www.kerrydeaf.com/net.png)

Video icon is missing on **iOS6 Simulator** as below:

[align top http://www.kerrydeaf.com/ios.png](http://www.kerrydeaf.com/ios.png)

Here is the CSS3:

```
 .blue_small {
 height: 40px;
 width: 40px;
 margin-left:16px;
 margin-bottom:6px;
 background-color:#fff;
 background:url(../images/index_video_small2.svg) no-repeat 5px 7px;
 -moz-border-radius: 50%; 
 -webkit-border-radius: 50%; 
 border-radius: 50%;
 border: 3px solid #fff;
 -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 2px 6px rgba(64,80,85,0.8);  
 box-shadow: 0px 2px 6px rgba(64,80,85,0.8);}
```

HTML5:

```
 <button class="blue_small" id="blue_small"></button>
```

How can I solve this to make icon appear the same in simulator as icon on **Firefox browser**, please?

UPDATE:

```
  <!DOCTYPE html>
  <html>
  <head>
  <title>APP</title>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
  <meta name="format-detection" content="telephone=no" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, width=device-width, height=device-height, target-densitydpi=device-dpi" /><!-- Cordova
```

Comment: Where's the background image for your button?

Comment: Sorry, I've left that out. It is in as above.  background:url(../images/index_video_small2.svg) no-repeat left 5px top 7px;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove `left` & `top`. Write like this:

```
background:url(../images/index_video_small2.svg) no-repeat 5px 7px;
```

**Instead of this :**

```
background:url(../images/index_video_small2.svg) no-repeat left 5px top 7px;
```

Comment: May be there are some other css which effect the IOS layout because the text in IOS is italic & misalign.

Comment: I'll accept this solution and changed the button background colour to white to hide the line. It worked on iPhone. I'll leave it at that and correct it later.